# The thymeleaf template does not display the date from the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am fairly new to spring boot so this is somewhat daunting for me in trying to display the date from a database (MySQL).

This is the view

```
<div class="exports">
                    <div class="box1">
                        <div class="col">
                            <h3>Latest Tracking Update</h3>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p th:if="${ latestTrackingUpdate  != null  }"
                                   th:text="${'Order ' + latestTrackingUpdate.status + ' on ' + formattedDate}">
                                    <!-- Display the latest tracking update details -->
                                </p>
                                <p th:if="${latestTrackingUpdate == null}">No tracking updates found.</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>                       
                    </div>
```

This is  the controller responsible for handling the date

```
@Controller
```

public class TrackingController {
private final TrackingService trackingService;

```
@Autowired
public TrackingController (TrackingService trackingService){
    this.trackingService = trackingService;
}

@GetMapping("/tracking")
public String getTrackingPage(Model model, @RequestParam(required = false) String searchTerm){
    Tracking latestTrackingUpdate = trackingService.getLatestTrackingUpdate(searchTerm);
    List<Tracking> trackingHistory = trackingService.getTrackingHistory(searchTerm);

    if (latestTrackingUpdate != null && latestTrackingUpdate.getTimestamp() != null) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(latestTrackingUpdate.getTimestamp());
        model.addAttribute("formattedDate", formattedDate);
    }

    model.addAttribute("latestTrackingUpdate", latestTrackingUpdate);
    model.addAttribute("trackingHistory", trackingHistory);
    model.addAttribute("searchTerm", searchTerm);
    return "tracking/tracking";
}
```

}

The controller is as follows:

```
    @Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Tracking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "order_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "order_seq", sequenceName = "order_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long trackingID;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String trackingNumber;
    private String status;
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    @PrePersist
    public void generateTrackingNumber(){
        this.trackingNumber = "NIF-" + trackingID;
    }
}
```

When i run the application, the date simple returns null on the view. What am i doing wrong?